# am trying to execute the query using the CONCAT function in the mysql console

Tags: mysql

the query is as follows

```
SELECT id, phonenumber CONCAT(  'A reminder for ', name, 'underfive number ', underfiveNO, 'for ', message,  'tomorrow.If shot was administered please ignore this message ' )
FROM appointment WHERE MONTH (current_date) = MONTH (appointmentdate) 
AND DAY (current_date) < DAY (appointmentdate) 
AND (NOT lastnotified = current_date) OR lastnotified IS NULL;
```

the error am getting is

> ERROR 1064(42000) you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '('A reminder for',name,'under five number',undefiveNo, 'for', message'at line1

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a comma

```
SELECT id, phonenumber, CONCAT( '...
                      ^-----------------herre
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be separator in between phonenumber and CONCAT() in your query: try with this

```
SELECT id, phonenumber, CONCAT('A reminder for ', name, ' underfive number ', underfiveNO, ' for ', message,  ' tomorrow. If shot was administered please ignore this message' )
FROM appointment WHERE MONTH (current_date) = MONTH (appointmentdate) 
AND DAY (current_date) < DAY (appointmentdate) 
AND ((NOT lastnotified = current_date) OR lastnotified IS NULL);
```

and also as you are adding a OR condition on lastnotified column, it should be enclosed with in paranthesis to meet either of the condition